# How to manipulate xticklabels and yticklabels in the heatmap of the seaborn package function?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

The data is aquired from a hdf file.

```
#Data Aquisition
file = h5py.File('filename.h5', 'r')

intensity = file.get('intensity')
intensity = np.array(intensity)

x_range = file.get('x range')
x_range = np.array(x_range)
x_range = np.round(x_range,1)

z_range = file.get('z range')
z_range = np.array(z_range)
z_range=np.flipud(np.round(z_range,1))
```

So I have two arrays (x_range and z_range) in the length of each direction of the heatmap data (z). I now want to skip ticklabels e.g. two show only 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, but must depend on the input arrays. The heatmap ist plotted using:

```
heat_map = sb.heatmap(intensity, yticklabels=z_range, xticklabels=x_range, cmap="Spectral_r")
plt.show()
```

[image: Heatmap]

I have tried to use:

```
heat_map.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
```

but it only reads the array one at a time and sets it at every 1/2 position in the heatmap and starts at 0.1.

[image]

But how can I set every fifth value of the arrays to every fifth position at the heatmap and starting at zero?

If you follow along the answers:
[image]

Comment: Please add more code. In particular, show how the variable `heat_map` was created. Preferably with some toy data to create a similar looking x-axis.  Note that [sns.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) doesn't return a heatmap. It returns a matplotlib `ax` on which the heatmap was created.  `ticker.MultipleLocator(5)` would put tick positions at every multiple of 5. So, 0,5,10,... as x-coordinate provided they are visible. In your case you would want `ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5)`.  Alternatively, you can call `heat_map.set_xticks([0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5])`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but I could not set the ticks via ```heat_map.set_xticks([0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5])``` instead I set them in the seaborn heatmap function via ```heat_map = sb.heatmap(np.zeros([26,26]), xticklabels=[0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5],cmap="Spectral_r", cbar_kws={'label': 'Countrate [arb. units]'})

heat_map.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))```
But now the problem ist, that the first ticker is 0.1 and not 0.

Comment: Ah, the confusion comes from the difference between the xticklabels (numbered 0.0, 0.1, ....) and the internal xticks (numbered 0,1,2,3,...). So you could try `heat_map.set_xticks(range(0, 25, 5))` or `heat_map.set_xticks(range(0, 25, 5))` or `heat_map.set_xticks(range(4, 25, 5))` or similar.

Comment: Ahh okay. So the range of the heatmap is enumerated as integers and I set each label at a certain integer position. But would it be possible to set a label centered to the datapoint e.g. that the first label wich would be zero is at label position 0.5? So that the 5 in the added picture (see above) is shifted to the last datapoint.

Comment: Something like `heat_map.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5, 25, 5))` and `heat_map.set_xticklabels(np.arange(0.0, 2.5, 0.5))` might work. Renaming `heat_map` to `ax` would make things less confusing.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It just works fine. Do you know a thread for smoothing the heatmap?

Comment: A contourplot with 256 levels might work